# Need help proving rigorously that if $|X|=1$, then the free group generated by $X$, $F(X)$, is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I can see this as being true since if $X=\{a\}$, then $F(X)$ must be an infinite cyclic group generated by $a$, which would then be isomorphic to $Z$.

Our teacher however asked us to prove the result by first showing that every non-empty word has an infinite order (which I did), and then use this fact to prove $F(X)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. I don't know how knowing the order of each element helps us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the function that takes $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ to $a^k\in F(X)$. Clearly this map is surjective (by definition of $F(X)$). Furthermore (as clearly as before) it is a group morphism. Hence by universal property of the quotient of groups :

$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{Ker(f)}\text{ is isomorphic to }F(X) $$

Now use your knowledge about $\mathbb{Z}$ to show that any non-trivial subgroup $H\leq \mathbb{Z}$ is of finite index in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Deduce from this (and what you have proven about the infinite order) that $Ker(f)$ cannot but be trivial. It follows that $f$ is one-to-one, and so it is an isomorphism.

Comment: I'm not seeing why I need to know every proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is finite indexed. Knowing only about the non-finiteness of the order of a word suffices, I think, to show the kernel is trivial.

Comment: This is every non-trivial subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. The fact that every non-trivial subgroup is of finite index imposes that every non-injective morphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ maps $\mathbb{Z}$ onto a finite group. Since $F(X)$ is not finite (because one of its element is of finite order) the morphism $f$ in my answer cannot but be injective. 

Finite index is important here because it imposes on the quotient finite order which contradict what you have proven... Both are needed.

Comment: I see now. Thanks for all your help.